# Please explain me this line of code

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a line code in XSLT but I don't understand some parts of it:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following::lieferant/text()=current()/text)">
        .
        .
        .
        .
 </xsl:if>
```

What does the line mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very nice invalid line of xpath :

```
"not(following::lieferant/text()0current()/text"
```

Where is the closing `)` ?

Maybe you meant this :

```
"not(following::lieferant/text() = current()/text())"
```

This would mean to check if the text() of the following lieferant element (Deutsch?) is not equal to the text of the current node (inside a foreach? )

But these are only guesses.

**Edit:**

```
"not(following::lieferant/text() = current()/text)"
```

So you say select all lieferant elements following the element you are currently in (following::lieferant) whose text content is not equal with the content of the text element of your current() node.

Comment: @BabakBst Does your current() node have a text element?

Answer (score 1):

**Very simply**:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following::lieferant/text()=current()/text)"> 
  <!-- Processing here ... -->
</xsl:if>
```

**means**:

Do the `"Processing here ..."` *only* if there isnt a `following::lieferant/text()` node that has the same string value as some of the `text` children of the current (matched by the current template or selected and processed by the innermost `xsl:for-each` instruction) node.

To put it in other words, there isn't a pair of nodes, one a `following::lieferant/text()`  and another a `current()/text` -- that both have the same string value.

**The provided code might be a typo for**:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following::lieferant/text()=current()/text())"> 
  <!-- Processing here ... -->
</xsl:if>
```

In this case the above explanation is still correct, except that the specified condition now is that: there isn't a pair of nodes, one a `following::lieferant/text()`  and another a `current()/text()` -- that both have the same string value.

In other words: None of the text nodes children of the currently matched (or selected by the innermost `xsl:for-each`) node has the same string value as that of any of the `following::lieferant/text()`  nodes.